# npm chai check returned object has property

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test my Promise with `chai`. My promise returns an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, Location: 'some where'},
  {id: 2, Location: 'over the rainbow'},
]
```

I keep getting this error but my test still passes:

```sh
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected [ Array(7) ] to have deep property 'Location'
```

My code:

```
describe('Function myPromise', () => {
    it(`should returns object with property Location`, () => {
       expect(myPromise(myParams)).to.eventually.have.deep.property('Location');
    });
});
```

I've also tried:

```
to.eventually.have.deep.property.include('Location');
to.eventually.have.property('Location');
to.eventually.be.an('array').and.have.property('Location');
return expect(myPromise(myParams)).to.eventually.have('Location');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out how to avoid that error. It's simpler and more straightforward than I thought:

```
describe('Function myPromise', () => {
    it(`should returns object with property Location`, () => {
       myPromise(myParams)
       .then((results) => {
         expect(results).to.be.an('array');
         results.forEach((result) => {
           expect(result).to.have.property('Location');
         });
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`have.deep.property` is applicable for checking object but seems like you checked the array.

Let me illustrate with a simple example

```
const fixtures = [
 {id: 1, Location: 'some where'},
 {id: 2, Location: 'over the rainbow'},
];

// I tested the first element
expect(fixtures[0]).to.have.deep.property('Location'); // passed
```

If you want to check every single element, you probably need a loop.

### Updates

To use loop to check every element, the first thing to do is to grab the fixtures from the promise function. In this way, I'm using `async/await` but you can use `promise` too.

```
describe("Function myPromise", () => {
  it(`should returns object with property Location`, async () => {
    const fixtures = await myPromise(myParams); // get the fixtures first

    // looping and check each element 
    fixtures.forEach(fixture =>
      expect(fixture).to.have.deep.property("Location"); // no need to use `eventually.have.deep` 
    );
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @deerawan. I understand it is an array and `deep.property` only checks one object. I was looking for a validation function without success. Something like `expect(myFunction(params)).forEach()`

Comment: @Viet you can try this one for checking each element `fixtures.forEach(fixture => expect(fixture).to.have.deep.property('Location'))`

Comment: Sorry @deerawan It won't work with the output of the Promise. In your example, fixtures is an array of objects, in my situation, it's a Promise function.

Comment: Hi @Viet, with that way, we need to grab `fixtures` first. I updated my answer to give you an idea about that. Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer doesn't solve the error. I actually have figured it out. I'll answer my question here.

Comment: @Viet Seeing your solution, I guess you can't use the async/await and use promise instead. That also works. I'm glad you solved it!

Comment: Thank you @deerawan

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) (or [chai-joi](https://github.com/raisch/chai-joi) in your case) to make schema validation very easy. I would definitely try this if you're going to be having many tests with object schema validation.

Comment: Thank you @Tom, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Well a promise is handled asynchronously. I believe you are missing the [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method in which will return the promise(rejected or fulfilled).

```js
describe('Function myPromise', () => {
    it(`should returns object with property Location`, () => {
       expect(myPromise(myParams).then(data => data).to.eventually.have.deep.property('Location');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn't work. I still have the error.